# Pandas Rolling Correlation Introduces Gaps

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a relatively clean data set with two columns and no gaps, a snapshot is shown below:

[image]

I run the following line of code:

```
correlation = pd.rolling_corr(data['A'], data['B'], window=120)
```

and for some reason, this outputs a dataframe (shown as a plot below) with large gaps in it:

[image]

I haven't personally seen this issue before, and am not sure after reviewing the data (more than the code) what the issue could be?

Comment: The same issue still persists, but thanks for the heads up. Interestingly rolling correlating a series against itself doesn't give 1, and also has the gaps in it too.

Comment: can you show your data ? not in pic ?

Comment: @Wen https://pastebin.com/WC8YLLNm

Comment: Getting error `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_corr'`

Answer (score 1):

It happens due to the missing dates in the time series, weekends etc. Evidence of this in your example being 7/2/2003 -> 10/2/2003. One solution is to fill in these gaps by re-indexing the time series dataframe.

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index) # required
df = df.asfreq('D') # reindex will include missing days
df = df.fillna(method='bfill') # fill / interpolate NaNs
corr = df.A.rolling(30).corr(df.B) # no gaps
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NAN values in your `correlation` variable where the number of rows is less than the value of the `window` attribute.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randn(10), 'B':np.random.randn(10)})
correlation = pd.rolling_corr(data['A'], data['B'], window=3)
print correlation
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.852602
3    0.020681
4   -0.915110
5   -0.741857
6    0.173987
7    0.874049
8   -0.874258
9   -0.835340
```

In the [docs for this function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_corr.html) is warns about this in the `min_periods` attribute section: "Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value (otherwise result is NA)."

It seems the default `None` is not working, since you'd think you wouldn't see the NaN unless you set a value for this.

Comment: HI Jeffery, I believe that should only be an issue at the beginning if I'm not mistaken, as once you have enough periods, it should start working (as in your example above).

The dates are not consecutive in every instance? Does this make a difference, or does it just go off consecutive rows do you know